# In JavaScript how to concat multiple files into an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert multiple files from a single directory into a single file containing an array of all the objects from the other files. For example each file contains a rule:

rule1.js:

```
rule = {
    rule: function(value){
        if (value==1){
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

and the final file should be as:

```
rules = [{rule1.js}, {rule2.js}..]
```

I need a final file in JS, looking for a something like gulp-concat, but into an array. any idea on how to do so?

Comment: Use a module system that is appropriate for whatever environment (browser, node.js, …) you are using.

Comment: rules = [{rule1.js}, {rule2.js}..] isn't working JS.

Comment: Although the content of the files is JavaScript, this kind of file manipulation can probably be better done with some batch scripting on the OS command line, or with some fancy text editor.

Comment: I could do it from from a shell, but I thought there might be a better solution, such as gulg-concat but more complex

Comment: Cpt. Meow Meow said:
> I need a final file in JS, looking for a something like gulp-concat, but into an array.

Comment: Are all the files in this format: `rule = { ... }` (spacing included)?

Comment: yep, all the rules are in that format of rule = {}, but I'm open to suggestions, just need a way to create an array of objects from multiple files

Comment: @Captain_Meow_Meow Then drop the assignment `rule = `, and just concat them with commas in between using your favourite file manipulation/build tool (shell, node.js script, python script, make, …). If you want to go native, use ES6 modules (with default exports) and import them in the module where you want to make an array from them.

Comment: @Bergi As I want to end up with a static file I'm not sure on how to achieve it with ES6 and export, any idea on how to export file into a single one and then create a static out of it?

Comment: @Captain_Meow_Meow Module bundlers do create a single static file from multiple modules.

Comment: @Bergi can you answer with a working example :)?